# Database structure in Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to think of the best solution for storing user's data in firebase, considering scalability, queries etc...

For example: Each user can create a list of categories. I was thinking of storing it like so:

```
Categories (Collection)
 - User ID (Document)
    - Category ID
       - title
       - imageURL
```

I would like to access the categories collection, find a list of all user ID's and when accessing a user ID I find their list of all the categories they have created...

I am quite new to firebase...

Or should I create Categories(collections) - User ID (document) - Category Id (collection) - title etc (document) ? Just does not seem right....

I appreciate any assistance or tips!

Edit: This is how I am currently saving the data to Firebase from my IOS app:

Model:

```
struct Category: Codable, Identifiable {
@DocumentID var docId: String?
var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
var authorId: String
var title: String
var categoryImageUrl: String?
```

Save data function:

```
  guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return } // REMOVE
     
     let db = Firestore.firestore() // REMOVE
     let collectionRef = db.collection("Categories").document(userId)
     do {
         try collectionRef.setData(from: category)
    }
     catch {
         print(error)
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with iOS, Swift, or SwiftUI.

Comment: @HangarRash well it has to do with uploading the data to firebase, and how I would setup the code to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a comprehensive answer, but one thing to keep in mind is that the client-side SDKs for Firestore don't have an API to get a list of (sub)collection. So it's important that your application can *know* the collection names without that, either because they are hard-coded (most common) or because they are stored elsewhere (such as in the parent document).

Comment: Hi Frank, appreciate your help. I would be retrieving the user's Id from a ''group'', and then with these id's I would like to retrieve all categories related to them. I just thought if I have all the categories in a collection named with the user id, it would be faster to retrieve them. Rather than filtering through alll th categories and taking just the ones with the user id's I am searching with... Not sure if that makes sense!

Comment: Firestore query/read performance does not depend on the number of documents in a collection, but **only** on the number of documents you retrieve.

Comment: Ok that's good to know... Thank you. What about collections - sub-collections etc, is there e a good time to use this or not? Sorry about all the questions!

Comment: It's hard to give a comprehensive answer, as the question is just too broad for that. I tried to explain Firestore's most important USP that many devs overlook when modeling their data. Aside from that, I recommend giving it a try - and possibly watching [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) for a broader introduction.